# Is my workload too big?

Tags: workflow, marketing, work, error

I work as the only designer in a marketing agency.

A lot of the time I have a day to produce a whole packaging design, another day to produce a suite of social assets and a couple of infographics, sometimes I have a day to produce a rebrand.

A lot of the time things overshoot and I have to continue the next day so things pile up a lot.

I have not worked with another company before, and the volume of work and speed that it needs to be done is causing continuity errors even when I am sure I am throughly checking.

I do not have experience to tell if this is normal for agency work.

Comment: This isn't a good question for this site. Every employment position is different. Some are more demanding than others. There really is no "normal" workload.

Comment: I'd also point out that it's important for you to express to others how much time you may need for things. Time necessary for creative endeavors is exceptionally difficult to quantify for those who do not have creative-based positions. Salesmen, managers, account executive, etc. all have *no clue* how long it should take to create *anything*. It's up to you to express that you need time to be effective. Start small and eventually you can "train" the non-creatives to understand that your position is not as simple as just pushing around a mouse for an hour.

Comment: @Scott the fact that others can not gauge time to do something is a typical problem to every expert field. Anyway it is also important to not work oneself to death.

Comment: @joojaa True. But in my experience, positions which are creative in nature, and using digital tools, can often be looked at like *any* other position using a computer. No time is given for conceptualization or ideation unless you force others to give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to tell. If you feel it is then it is probably true for you. But lets see about the cause and effect here.

- One of the hardest part of being a new worker in any expert field is that there is a huge change between your education and the work that you end up doing.

  In your education there were maybe 10 or 20 different things. And you tried to be as good as you possibly could.

  In worklife those things are either 1-2 or 25. But the aim may no longer be top notch it may be lower in quality or it might be higher in some regard if the workplace is really focused.

  So the disparity between what you think the output should be and what your internal clients need might be different.
- Learn to say no! Its hard to come in terms with the fact that you need to make the tasks given work for yourself.

  Thing is you will be given more and more tasks over time. Simply because the organisation wants more value out of you. But its your duty to communicate with your immediate manager as to what you should prioritize. This will teach them to allocate you better and it will teach you to prioritize better.
- In your formative years there was always time allocated for you to learn. Now you need to push back to get that time. It is simply assumed that you know how to work all relevant tools.

  But this may not be true. For several reasons students are rarely so proficient that choosing the right tool for the job is a procrastination free action. You will get better at this.*
- Learn also what other people do. There might be tasks that you are supposed to delegate to others.

* when I compare myself to students who are graduating with their Master's im still easily 3-4 times faster than they are in certain procedural/mechanical core skills. Though no faster than them in thinking speed just less times wasted. That and better tools, it takes time to collect useful shortcuts for your specific work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it definitely sounds like too much work.

However, this is not uncommon in marketing. Some countries will have a limit on day hours and such, no overtime, no weekend work, but in most places it probably is a "whatever it takes" situation.

If I was in your position I would 100% try to negotiate the terms of this employment, with regard to hours or payment.

FYI here's an eye opening statement. If you did all that work as a freelancer you would probably be making a lot more money and you would have some relative control over your workload.